# find: `var/cache/django/...': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, find

This cron job:

```
@daily find var/cache -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -mtime +14 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Creates sometimes error messages like this:

```
find: `var/cache/django/bfcfd153d35a27eb78823.djcache': No such file or directory"
```

It happens sometimes. Not often.

What could be the reason? How to avoid this?

Version: find (GNU findutils) 4.5.10

Comment: A cache file which is already removed normally by the django service ? When find try to remove it, it doesn't exists anymore. You may see the "-delete" option

Comment: The cron job should be the only process which deletes files in this directory. Maybe there is an other process which I am not aware of up to now. Thank you for this hint.